# Why do override functions not have sender object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C# and when I was creating a custom control in asp, a question created in my mind: why do override functions not have a `sender` object?

For example:

```
protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

but when we use this event in code, there is a variable of type object named "sender"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These methods starting with *On* don't need to receive *who has raised the event* because, since they're part of the sender, `this` is *the sender* (the instance of the class declaring the whole events).

When some subscribes to a given event, it may hàppen that it could be another class and you might need to know who has raised the event.

Answer (score 0):

Methods with signatures like `protected override void On*(*EventArgs e)` are there to allow derived types to raise events defined in parent classes. Since these are the methods that raise the event for their own instance all that they need is to use `this` to get the sender object.

Comment: thank you too, but I can only choose one "correct answer"